# How to properly use string encryption in Dotfuscator?

Tags: c#, xamarin, encryption, xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

I am developing an Application with Xamarin Forms and my App has to call several APIs with specific API-Keys.
Therefore I want to encrypt them so that nobody can decompile my App package and extract the Keys.
Thats the reason why I want to use Dotfuscator but I am having trouble to get it to encrypt these strings.
Here is my code where I created a litte public class with the only purpose of saving my keys:

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace App
{
    public class Data
    {
        [ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "stringencryption", Exclude = false, ApplyToMembers = true)]
        public static string GetAPIKey()
        {
            string we = "MYAPIKEY";
            return we;
        }
    }
}
```

When I decompile the .dll with ILSpy I can easily extract the key from it, nothing gets encrypted like in this example https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/quickstart/en/feature_obfuscation_string_encryption.html

The "normal" renaming by Dotfuscator works just fine in this .dll.
Obfuscation attributes are also activated for this .dll in my DotfuscatorConfig.xml.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Windows? Web?

Comment: Its cross-plattform for Android and iOS via Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Could you build your own API which does all the calls to the other APIs? Then you could hide all your keys on the server hosting your API

Comment: You're right that would be the "best" method to solve my problem but I dont want to rely on another server between my calls.
There has to be a way to encrypt my string like in the Dotfuscator example.

Comment: I just learned that this featue is exclusive for the Professional Edition of Dotfuscator...
Thats disappointing.

Comment: Agreed, they always find a way to make you pay for something useful, lol.

Comment: @Zhorrid In general, it is a bad idea to hard code private API keys and even with Dotfuscator someone can still decode those strings...